# Is it possible to use a variable that has been declared in vb in xslt?

Tags: vb.net, xslt

In my xslt file I want to apply templates to the xml but only if an id of that piece of content within the xml matches an id calculated in vb.

Hopefully some code will make this clearer:

```
<xsl:variable name="ContentparId" select="/Page/descendant::Content/@parId"/>
<xsl:variable name="parIdfromfref" select="mnPageId"/>

<xsl:template match="Page">
    <xsl:if test="$ContentparId = $parIdfromfref">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/Page" mode="addModule">
```

ContentparId is the attribute parId of Content in the xml. I want to compare this with mnPageId which is defined in vb (a foreign reference is passed through and the pageId that matches that foreign reference is returned)

I know the rest of the code does what I want it to do because if I manually change mnPageId for a correct pageId then I get the xml that I want back.

So, is it possible to use a variable that has been declared in vb in xslt? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well an XSLT stylesheet can have global parameters in the form of

```
<xsl:param name="mnPageId"/>
```

that can be set from outside the stylesheet before an XSLT transformation is run programmatically. So that is a possible approach, define `mnPageId` as a global stylesheet parameter that your VB code running the transformation then sets as needed. You can read up the section on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfktf882.aspx on how to set parameters with .NET code when running a transformation.

Comment: Turns out I can avoid having to do this, but reading through what you've put seems like it would have helped me do what I needed to so I've set it as the accepted answer. Thanks for the help.